# How can I improve questions that are looking for personal advice?

Tags: discussion

When I look at the questions, most are looking for personal advice, but somehow cannot state the question in terms abstract enough so to only state it as a question about Islam.

Recent example is [Is the talaq counted](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/80799/55518) .

I heard (citation needed) that a divorce has to be issued three times to be valid (to avoid a divorce out of monetarily bad emotions) and it is also not valid to repeat the divorce three times in a row.

So I would like to improve this question (and others, as the show up) by asking a question less centered on personal circumstances. And learn more myself.

How can I best do that? Ask a new question with a link to the original? Misuse the "answer" feature to state the question? Add a comment (allowed text probably to short)?

Comment: Your example question is a bad choice to ask for improvement since questions fo talaq are a topic in which a one-to-one situation between the mufti and the husband is necessary to get all information and speak out a verdict. This beside dream-interpretation is a topic which certainly can't be answered online.

Comment: @Medi1Saif maybe that bad example is a good example in that it points to the difficulties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I joined the site years ago the first thing I've noticed is that there are 3-4 kinds of Question posts:

- One asking for information on a topic that really needs some background knowledge or even if the information might be available the questioner wants to dig deeper.
- One asking for easily available information and doesn't want to dig deeper or is too lazy to check for it.
- And one asking for personal help or fatwa.
- All kinds of spam: Statements, promotion for a site or tool, rude and abusive posts etc..

The first kind is on-topic without any doubt.
The second is tricky: is it laziness? Is it a kind of missed homework question? shall we distinguish whether the person asking is Muslim, non-Muslim, practicing-Muslim, non-practicing Muslim...?
The third is the kind you're pointing at and I'll try to answer it below.
As for the fourth, it often is easy to detect and can be marked sooner or later as off-topic/closed/deleted etc.

It was and still sometimes is difficult to handle all this because I wanted to (help by) answer(ing) to the best of my knowledge.

I won't pretend that I have the solution for the 3rd kind at hand, but here are some of my actions and some of the corresponding lessons learned:

- Sometimes I have answered such questions by explaining the legal framework - as far as I know - including the various interpretations of madhhabs etc.. But I didn't answer the personal question and just answered that the questioner should know the case better or could now have enough hints to answer the question. Another option for me that seems ok is to say hey your question is too personal, but I can explain or at least give you the legal framework as a hint.
  I think both of these options are fine.
- Sometimes I might have given some advice after explaining the legal framework.
  Additional advice should not be the rule but the exception, but at times you read a post and get the feeling this person might need it so I have chosen to do it. I didn't care whether the question was closed as off-topic later.
- Another option is to rephrase the post to make it sound more like a concise question: This might honestly be the best solution from a site policy perspective, but it takes effort and effort, especially when considering the question answer. First of all, the questioner's "question" has been reformulated and perhaps he will come back and not agree with this "editing". This means that the answer may no longer be applicable because the question is different. Then it is entirely possible that the newly formulated question has already been answered, i.e. it would be a duplicate. Further it is also possible that you misinterpreted the question and hopefully got a hint from the questioner to re-edit it in the correct manner.
  Nevertheless, this type of processing seems to me to be qualitatively better, especially when you take into account that, with a few exceptions, most questions of this type come from users who pop in here once and then never come back.
- Sometimes the best solution is simply to leave the question be closed (and vote for its closure) and if you feel like you have found a hint of an answer or a good answer you could still share links to fatwas and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a lot of questions which are asking for personal advice is that they're not actually looking for knowledge: They're looking for *help*.

This is fundamentally a very different type of question; someone who is dealing with a difficult situation is unlikely to be consoled by cold hard fact. They don't want to know the truth so much as they just want someone to take their hand and say everything's going to be okay. Maybe let's grab a coffee and you can tell me all about it.

Taking the question you linked as an example, that doesn't read to me as someone who actually wants to know the truth of the ruling; it's someone who wants the ruling they already think is true to not be true.

And the sad truth is, that's just not what Stack Exchange was made for. The whole system is explicitly designed to cut through the noise, the niceties and human elements that may be critical in a social context but which tend to obfuscate actual information. We strip away all that so all the kernels of knowledge can be identified and found again quickly and easily.

That's why giving personal advice is difficult if not impossible on Stack Exchange sites; people who want *help* aren't looking for answers, they're looking for sympathy, and they're not going to get that from a cold fact-based peer-supported voting engine. There's a reason why encyclopedias and self-help books are on different shelves in the library; they serve very different purposes by communicating in very different ways.

This is one of the major reasons why we have the disclaimer on the main page that suggests people should be "seeking such advice from your Mufti, Imam, or other trustworthy Counselor." Not only are they the ones best equipped to recognize the difference between a call for help and a pursuit of knowledge, they are also in a position to provide whatever social support is necessary, or even just a sympathetic ear.

All that said, if they have enough network reputation you can try to redirect these issues to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=islam.stackexchange.com), which *does* allow the sort of freedom and open social support they'd need, that the main site can't provide.

Comment: Your response is not an answer to my question, so I cannot click on the *accept* button, but it is much, much more valuable. This site is on facts only, and cannot be any other way. In one of my earliest posts I was referring to some (lost) site that answered personal questions,  It was about 2001, and I cannot find it any more. It was intended to *help* people.